# M/18/5'5"/105lbs (1.6m/48kg) I want to gain weight

Tags: diet, muscle, weight-gain

I want to gain weight and muscle so I need a good diet. Unfortunately, I get full too quick and I don't know what to do to eat more.

My goal is to reach 55kg.

What do you guys think I should do?

Comment: This will probably get closed as a duplicate (as it pretty much is), but one thing I'd like to add is if you're stuggling to eat enough, you need to view eating as you would do training; you need to train yourself to eat more. One of the keys to weight training is progressive overload, so adding a little more weight over a long period. Train your eating the same, eat a little more each meal every day.

Comment: Get 1%  better everyday... just increase your training and eating like that and you should be fine.  Don't suddenly  eat 3000 calories... start slow and take it easy

Answer (score 0):

Hey I used to be underweight too (58kg) and I'm now lean 77kg at 180cm. I've got some tips.

-Don't smoke or do drugs obviously as they kill your appetite and eating schedule

-Eat snacks, do not skip any meal. Often skinny people skip breakfast, and eat a huge meal in the evening and then think they ate enough.

-Count calories! This will give you an idea of how much you're eating. This is to prevent you from eating too little and thinking it's enough, happens a lot with beginners. After counting calories for a few weeks you'll get a feeling of what is enough.

Comment: Perfect  answer, short and clear, doesn't  need anything more.

Answer (score 0):

I struggle to gain weight too. The solution is not to try and eat bigger meals (not at first anyway), but to eat more regularly. Instead of 3 meals a day try and consume something 6 times a day - this is where protein shakes are useful. My routine when I was bulking was something like this:

7am - breakfast (oats + yoghurt + protein)
10am - protein shake 3 scoops
midday - lunch (chicken breast + microwave rice pouch)
3pm - banana + protein shake
5pm - gym session
7pm - dinner (carbs + protein)

It can be hard work, especially eating when you aren't hungry, but you get used to it and just have to stick to a schedule. At first I really struggled with the chicken + rice at lunch because I had no appetite, but I just sat at my desk at work and ploughed through it.

Using that schedule and training 5 times a week I managed to get my weight from 79kgs to 85kgs in just over 3 months, mostly lean muscle as well. (I'm 6'2 so quite a bit taller).